# What was the exact philosophy of Swāmi Vivekānanda?

Tags: vedanta, advaita, vivekananda

From [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/17457/8696) answer we find the following quote of Swāmi Vivekānanda:

> ...You can swallow the stars by the handful if you want; such is your **real** nature...

Further, from [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/16922/8696) answer we find the **real nature** of Nīrguna Brahman is not omnipotent enough to swallow the stars, moreover Nīrguna Brahman is inactive. ( Actually stars ain't existing on plane of **our real nature**, then also the quote doesn't make any sense )So according to Advait/Sankara Vedànta, Swāmi Vivekānanda shouldn't have said so because such is not our **real** nature (real nature is Nīrguna/inactive).

Then what exactly was the philosophy of Swāmi Vivekānanda? Or I'm **missing** something? In any case please answer.

Comment: You are taking Vivekananda literally. Vivekananda is saying that as Brahman we are far more than weak human beings. 'Swallowing the stars by handfull' is a metaphor and not to be taken literally.

Comment: Oh. Would think on this. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He once again expounded the entire Hindu philosophy. He never claimed it as his own brand, but did mention personal religious  experiences that he verified, reinforcing beliefs and sharing his feelings convincingly with all.