# Is Muhurtham not necessary in hinduism?

Tags: belief

Ram Devbaba (yoga guru) said Muhurtham is not necessary, for example; we see Muhurtham for marriages, which is not necessary according to him.

([Source](http://bharatswabhimansamachar.in/i-have-no-believe-on-astrology-said-swami-ramdev/))

What Hindu Scriptures saying about this matter?

Comment: Fixing Muhurtham or auspicious time is absolutely necessary for most vedic karma - especially upanayana and vivaha, which are the 2 most important of all samksaras for boys & girls respectively. Jyotisha shastra (one of the 6 vedangas) deals with how to fix muhurtam based on position of gruhas.

Comment: It is his personal opinion about astrology. His words need not to be taken serious. We can find some examples of fixing of auspicious muhurtas in scriptures too. They are important.

Comment: [Swami Vivekananda did not believe in astrology](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/17381/2995), Swami Chinmayananda did not believe in astrology or vaastu. Follow the greats, the saints. They did not believe in these things. So many marriages fail despite the best muhūrtas. Think for yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Muhurtham is necessary or not is totally depends on your believes. Muhurthams are rules or rituals evolved by our ancestors, and they made these rules to maintain a culture. However, if anyone not believing or maintaining these rules are not wrong, he/she only have a different perspective on it. Muhurthams are not God written golden rules, so they are not going to affect your daily life if you don't follow them. However following these rules makes a society and a culture.

You just listen to your heart and mind, and whatever your instincts are showing you, your soul will follow that-you will follow that.

However these are all my way of point, it may differ from yours or others. And also I didn't mean to hurt anybody's feeling, so take it just as a usual talk.

Comment: Welcome. Personal opinions are not considered as valid sources as per our site rules. If you have any sources, please add them in your answer.