# What is the age limit of getting a yajnopavita for various castes?

Tags: scripture, caste-system, yagnopavitam

What is the age limit as per the scriptures of getting a Yajnopavita for the various varnas?

Comment: Your question is already answered here so Im marking it duplicate: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2892/is-janeva-yaj%C3%B1opav%C4%ABtam-or-sacred-thread-limited-to-brahmins-only

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Janeva (Yajñopavītam or sacred thread) limited to Brahmins only?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2892/is-janeva-yaj%C3%B1opav%C4%ABtam-or-sacred-thread-limited-to-brahmins-only)

Comment: @Sinister How is that duplicate? Question clearly asks about age but that question has no relation to age.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Well, you should asked that question to Vishal Prabhu Lawande. The question is already answered there. So, I only reviews the post, Didn't initiate the close vote. Answers make the duplicate or the questions make the duplicate? If it is former, it is dupe other wise, it is not.

Comment: @Sinister then why did you close to vote even after knowing rule?

Comment: @TheDestroyer Which rule does our site follow? Questions making duplicates or answers making duplicate? Different sites follow different rules. I am unclear about ours.

Comment: @Sinister Obviously questions make duplicates which i informed [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17381/did-swami-vivekananda-believe-in-astrology#comment45493_17381).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Ideal time to perform the sacred thread ceremony:**

> Manu Smriti 2.36. In the eighth year after conception, one should
>   perform the initiation (upanayana) of a Brahmana, in the eleventh
>   after conception (that) of a Kshatriya, but in the twelfth that of a
>   Vaisya

**The maximum age limits till which sacred thread ceremony can still be performed for the three varnas:**

> Manu Smriti 2.38. The (time for the) Savitri (initiation) of a
>   Brahmana does not pass until the completion of the sixteenth year
>   (after conception), of a Kshatriya until the completion of the
>   twenty-second, and of a Vaisya until the completion of the
>   twenty-fourth.

And if Upanayana is not performed even within those prescribed time limits, then this is what happens as per Manu:

> 2.39. **After those (periods men of) these three (castes) who have not received the sacrament at the proper time, become Vratyas (outcasts)**,
>   excluded from the Savitri (initiation) and despised by the Aryans

Comment: ok the Brahmana here means son of Brahmana right?

Comment: Yes., that's right @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury

Comment: And what if I am a son of a Vratya? Can I get initiation?

Comment: I am a Kshatriya by varna but neither my father nor my grandfather got initiation so they are Vratyas right. Can I get initiation then?

Comment: This can not be answered so simply. I think it depends on how many generations have elapsed without undergoing upanayana. Also by initiation u must be meaning Gayatri mantra initiation right? @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury

Comment: Yes exactly and I myself don't know how many generations have passed. Even my family members have no idea about it.

Comment: Ok.. i think as per some other scriptures it can still be done after going through some prayaschittas. @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury

Comment: What is the prayaschitta then?

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury I will have to search the question then, it will take some time.

Comment: Ok and what happens if you chant Gayatri mantra before initiation?

Comment: As per Smritis Sudras (or one who is not initiated) should not chant Om, Swaha, Gayatri and few others. As per Agamas no mantras should be chanted without Diksha (initiation). So, its better to get a Dilksha before chanting. I can't tell for sure what will exactly happen, but i don't think it will be  something good. :) @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury

Comment: Omg I have sinned

Comment: Do not think like that way.. God will take care..Its not a sin. @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury

Comment: I hope so @Rickross

Comment: @Rickross, for gayatri, it is 3 generations passed without chanting.

Comment: @ram Kanchi Paramacharya mentions 3 Generations but do any scripture mention it??

Comment: @SethuSrivatsaKoduru - pretty sure he doesn't speak without scriptural backing.

Comment: @ram Very true. But could you give any verse of SHastra which says so?