# What are days I can have an oil massage (abhyangana snana) on head or on body?

Tags: practice, dharma-shastras, customs

There is already a question about [Shaving / Haircut / Nailcut - what days are allowed / prohibited?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10025/shaving-haircut-nailcut-what-days-are-allowed-prohibited). So, I want to know the days I can take an oil massage (otherwise called as Abhyangana snana) including weekdays as well as the days as per the lunar calendar followed by us.

Comment: It is related to Hinduism as there are days I know of as per our scriptures where we can’t shave or have an haircut like sat tue and sun

Comment: Please read this  answer. - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/5205/5620

Comment: @SwiftPushkar, how do you know it is not related to Hinduism ? Are you aware of dharma shastras ? Yes, it varies according to regions. Andhra follows lunar calendar, TamilNadu follows solar. Does that mean both are wrong? It is addressed in scriptures. If you don't know, say you don't know and leave it at that. That link you posted is from someone who is not conversant with orthodox brahmana ways of life.

Comment: Saturday is the recommended day for oil massage & bath. There is a saying in Tamil for this ('shani neeradu'). Every week may not be possible. Some of us don't even do it for years. But once a month is practical. @RahulK, you're right.. should not cut hair or nails on the day when you're having oil bath. see this answer for restrictions on that - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10025/shaving-haircut-nailcut-what-days-are-allowed-prohibited

Comment: @SwiftPushkar It is not at all easy to determine which subjects has been discussed in scriptures and which are not... So, that's why i never try to close Qs because i can never be very sure.. also Hindu scriptures discuss virtually everything IMO.. See this meta post i am highlighting the same point in the answer there  https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1131/is-what-scriptures-xyz-say-about-my-off-topic-query-a-freeway-to-conver

Comment: @Rickross - Yes i do agree with you on above point. but Dharma-Bindu is just the essence of Dharma-Shastras. Its quite possible that we may never get the full idea about its source or context from that. So basically ithe book is not scripture.

Comment: But it is quoting from scriptures only.. don't u see the Maharishis name?.. they are also giving the sanskrit slokas.. so we can guess that they are from the Puranas or some other scriptures.. @SwiftPushkar Also Abhyanga Snana belongs to Hinduism..DOn't u know about the Naraka Chaturdashi?

Comment: @SwiftPushkar Books like Dharma Bindhu , essence of Dharma Sindhu are directly quoting from scriptures only.. Otherwise what's the use of them? It is handy for us to have such books with us..because we can not really go through every possible Hindu scriptures before coming to a conclusion on a topic..

Answer (score 6):

You are basically asking about *Abhyanga Snana* (oil massage followed by bath). And scriptures definitely talk about that..

The [book Dharma Bindu](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjL4_vq66XZAhWMM48KHYJyAIQQFggmMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.kamakoti.org%2Fkamakoti%2Farticles%2FDharma%2520Bindu.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1x3Jos4XEvGBXF9vB0HyY8) (hosted by the Kamakoti.org) has the details:

> Bharadwaaja Maharshi details these snanas as follows: Abhyanga
>   snaapane yogyaa vaaraaye tithibhissaha,
>  Kathyate tethunaa spashtam
>   pushtaye balavriddhaye/
>  Indorbudhasya sourescha vaarebhyangam
>   prashasyate kaantim,
>  Shriyam tathaa dadyuh bhogaan vaaraadhipaah
>   kramaat/
>  Dwiteeyaadyaashchatasrascha prashastaah Saptami tathaa,
>   Navami Dashami chaiva Trayodashyapi cha smritaah/
>  Bhaanu
>   bhoumaamaraachaarya Shukravaareshu sankrame,
>  Vyatipaatecha
>   Janmakshenaabhyangam snaanamaacharet/
>  Ekadashyaam charurdashyaam
>   Ashtamyaam pratipadyapi,
>  Shashtyaam Parvaani chaabhyanga snaanamnaiva
>   samaacharet/ 
> Uttaraa phalguni jyeshthaa Shavanaardraasu raatrishu,
>   Abhyanga snaapanam dheemaan sukhardhi varjayettathaa/
>   Shishurogaarta vriddhaanaam yathaakaalam shareerinaam,
>   Abhyangoshnodaka snaanam naiva doshaavaham smritam/
>
> Abhyangana Snaanas prescribed for health and strength are prescribed
>   as follows: Monday, Wednesday and Sunday are excellent for these as
>   they grant brightness, opulence and enjoyment respectively. Tithiwise,
>   Dvitteya-Triteeya-Chaturthi-Panchami, Saptami, Navami and Trayodashi
>   are auspicious. But, Sunday-Tuesday-Thursday- Friday Samkramana timings,
>   Janma Nakshatras, Vyatipata timings are avoidable. Also, Ekadashi,
>   Chaturdashi,Ashtami,Prathama,Shashti and Pournamai are unworthy.
>   Uttara Phalguni, Jyeshtha, Shravana, Ardra nakshatras are to be
>   avoided. Children, persons suffering from diseases and old aged are
>   exempt from the above restrictions and might bathe with hot water.

This above list has the details of the prescribed days based on Vara, Tithi etc.

Comment: Why can’t a person have the right to knowledge and practice as per his own will. I find some folks here bent on showing that modern lifestyle does not permit following these points laid down ages back. You guys don’t follow no one is forcing you but do not and do not I say again push or force your thoughts on any one else. Upvote or down vote I don’t care.. thanks @rickcross I was looking for this information itself.

Comment: @RahulK, folks like S K are the modern 'social-reformers' who also like to show off their command of english language.. don't pay much heed to their idioticities.

Comment: This is definitely a good answer. Dharma shastras talk about these practices and hence on-topic for this site. And @SK this site is about Hinduism and Hinduism is not originated only in 2018.

Comment: @TriyugiNarayanMani  Yes that's exactly what i am trying to explain here: https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1133/4732