# Which texts are infallible and inerrant?

Tags: scripture, vedas, puranas, bhagavad-gita, smriti

The Vedas must be infallible, as they were authored by God, or by rishis under the inspiration of God, who is the “Truth of Truth”. Therefore every passage of the Vedas is true, whether literally or metaphorically. Sometimes they may be misinterpreted, but then the fault lies with the reader, not with the text.

However the Smritis and Puranas cannot be infallible, as they sometimes conflict with the Vedas, and with each other.

What other texts are infallible or infallible? Is the Bhagavad Gita infallible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is source for claim that Sruti is more important than Smriti ? That Itihasa/Purana can be discarded if they conflict with Vedas?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/36809/what-is-source-for-claim-that-sruti-is-more-important-than-smriti-that-itihasa)

Answer (score 1):

Only Vedas and not any other text are considered to be infallible. However, infallibility does not mean that every passage and every word is literally true.

> The appeal to the infallibility of the Vedic injunction is
> misconceived. **The infallibility in question refers only to the unseen
> forces or apurva, and is admissible only in regards to matters not
> confined to the sphere of direct perceptions, etc ... Even a hundred
> statements of sruti to the effect that fire is cold and non-luminous
> won't prove valid. If it does make such a statement, its import will
> have to be interpreted differently. Otherwise, validity won't attach
> to it. Nothing in conflict with the means of valid cognition or with
> its own statements may be imputed to sruti.**

**REF: Srimad Bhagavad Gita Bhasya of Sri Sankaracarya translation by Dr. A. G. Krishna Warrier, p. 629.**

Here is another example of how the greats have viewed the Vedas.

**Vedas and Reason**

> 35. **Personally I take as much of the Vedas as agrees with reason.** Parts of the Vedas are apparently contradictory. They are not
>     considered as inspired in the Western sense of the word, but as the
>     sum total of the knowledge of God, omniscience. This knowledge comes
>     out at the beginning of a cycle and manifests itself; and when the
>     cycle ends, it goes down into minute form. When the cycle is projected
>     again, that knowledge is projected again with it. So far the theory is
>     all right. But that only these books which are called the Vedas are
>     His knowledge is mere sophistry. **Manu says in one place that that part
>     of the Vedas which agrees with reason is the Vedas and nothing else.
>     Many of our philosophers have taken this view.**
> 36. Of all the scriptures of the world **it is the Vedas alone that declare that even the study of the Vedas is secondary. The real study
>     is "that by which we realise the Unchangeable". And that is neither
>     reading, for believing, nor reasoning, but superconscious perception,
>     or Samâdhi.**

**The Complete Works of Swami Vivekananda, Vol 5, Sayings and Utterances**

Comment: lol.. you're quoting a Smriti to say that only Sruti is perfect while Smriti is imperfect ? Why not quite Sruti itself, if possible, as asked in this [question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/36809/do-vedas-mention-that-vedas-alone-are-to-be-followed-and-itihasa-purana-should-b)

Comment: He isn't saying that the Vedas are not infallible, he's saying that is has to be INTERPRETED to be in line with reason.

Comment: @mar It's embarrasing that you think the Puranas are infallible. They explicitly contradict each other and the Vedas but you think they are infallble?

Comment: @mar Also how can the texts be talking about the Puranas and Itihasas that we have? They were composed after the Vedas were composed so how is that possible?

Comment: @mar I would trust Smritis to speak about themselves. If you assume otherwise, than you are saying that they are fallible.

Comment: @TargiKoor - i don't think that all Puranas are infallible. Only Satvik Puranas are cos there is no contradiction within them.

Comment: @TargiKoor - Vedas are Trikala Gynani. They can talk about past, present and future. So nothing wrong to expect they can talk about Smritis composed in future.

Comment: @TargiKoor - If Smriti says *"Don't believe me"* - should THAT be believed ? that itself is a contradiction. Why do people suddenly choose to believe that portion of Smriti if they are staunch believers of Vedas ALONE ? Let them show which Vedic verse says *"Believe Smriti only if it contradicts with Shruti"*

Comment: While speaking on the Vedas, we must remember the fact that the Vedas available to us are incomplete.